# Rotating the screen resets variables

Tags: android

When I rotate the phone, the screen rotates too. But the problem is when the screen rotates, the variables reset.

My `onCreate()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actjogo);
    getActionBar().hide();
    change();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when the screen rotates, the entire `Activity` is destroyed, and then recreated. There are two ways to handle this:

1. You can save the state of your screen in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and then set those values again in `onCreate()`.
2. You can add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to Activity elements in your manifest.

Comment: Ok, i see some foruns and i see that code: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` and this work, at least i dont see error

Comment: Yes, this is the other way of handling rotation, and can often be much easier.

Comment: It's a bandaid, not a fix. You should still properly save your state in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onCreate()`. Your activity will still be destroyed and recreated for other configuration changes (such as a locale change or a SIM removal/insertion).

Comment: Thanks, Edited my answer to include your alternate solution.